# How to change file-timestamp from filename-information

Tags: file, rename, batch-rename

i have a lot of files that are in the following formats:
`xxxxxxxxx - dd-mm-yyyy hh-mm.mp3` (number of x may varies)
example "`NANO - 10-07-2015 14-13.mp3`"

now these files are with wrong `timestamps`
while the correct time and date is enclosed in the filename

can anyone help me to do batch that put the time in the filename into the timestamp,
i have searched in deep over the internet and all i find is the vise versa of my scenario.
thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean, "these files are with wrong timestamps while the correct time and date is enclosed in the filename"? Could you post a screenshot of your file structure?